# Python click option based logging in decorator

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, python-click, python-logging

Fresh start. I have a CLI application that uses click for handling argument parsing. For the main "executable" script I have a defined verbosity flag (-v, -vv, -vvv, ...) that controls logging verbosity. I want to "trace" function calls for specific functions. Down below is a sample that hopefully will make it clear.

```
import click
import logging
import functools


class MyLogger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__logger = None

    def init_logger(self, name, verbosity):
        logging_levels = {0: logging.CRITICAL,
                          1: logging.ERROR,
                          2: logging.INFO,
                          3: logging.DEBUG}
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging_levels.get(verbosity, logging.WARNING))
        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    @property
    def logger(self):
        return self.__logger


myLogger = MyLogger()


class TraceFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def __call__(self, function):
        name = function.__name__

        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            self.logger.debug(f'{name}({list(*args)}, {dict(**kwargs)})')
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            self.logger.debug(f'{result}')
            return result

        return wrapped


# (1) @TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)
def echo(message):
    return message.upper()


@click.command('echo')
@click.option('-e', '--echo', 'message', required=True, type=str)
def echo_command(message):
    myLogger.logger.info('echo_command')
    return echo(message)


@click.group()
@click.option('-v', 'verbosity', count=True)
def main(verbosity: int):
    myLogger.init_logger(__name__, verbosity)
    # (2) TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)(echo)
    myLogger.logger.info('main')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.add_command(echo_command)
    main()
```

The above if executed will correctly produce the following output:

```
script.py -vv echo -e "Hello World"
INFO: __main__:main
INFO: __main__:echo_command
```

I want to "trace" the function: echo. More precisely I want to log the actual function call with the actual arguments and the returned value. Okay, a bit more than that but I needed a minimal sample. For this purpose I tried two things, labeled with (1) and (2) placed in comments.

```
@TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)
def echo(message):
    return message.upper()
```

It flat out doesn't work as with my original question python will execute TraceFunction.**call**(echo) before in "main" I call init_logger that essentially would configure the logger itself. As a result in TraceFunction.**call** the logger is None and I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'
```

Fine, I can register it later on, at least I thought with (2). Well the exception surely went away, however "wrapped" defined in **call** is never invoked and well once again nothing gets logged other than the already shown

```
script.py -vvv echo -e "Hello World"
INFO: __main__:main
INFO: __main__:echo_command
```

@Update
Going by afterburner's answer things go a bit further but it doesn't do what it's supposed to:

```
script.py -vvv echo -e "Hello World"
DEBUG:__main__:echo(['F','o','o'],{})
DEBUG:__main__:FOO
INFO: __main__:main
INFO: __main__:echo_command
```

Which well is expected. The expected output on the other hand would be:

```
script.py -vvv echo -e "Hello World"
INFO: __main__:main
INFO: __main__:echo_command
DEBUG:__main__:echo(['Hello World'],{})
DEBUG:__main__:HELLO WORLD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working but it sure is ugly... at least in its current form. The only needed change was:

```
@click.group()
@click.option('-v', 'verbosity', count=True)
def main(verbosity: int = 0):
    global echo

    myLogger.init_logger(__name__, verbosity)
    echo = TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)(echo)  # <<< !!!
    myLogger.logger.info('main')
```

In doing so the output becomes:

```
INFO:__main__:main
INFO:__main__:echo_command
TRACE:__main__:echo(['Hello World'], {})
TRACE:__main__:HELLO WORLD
```

So the answer was, that I completely missed:

```
TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)(echo)
```

is fine, but I needed to assign it to the original echo function:

```
echo = TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)(echo)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the main issue I can see is that you're not calling the wrapped function.

```py
TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)(echo)
# vs
 TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)(echo)()
```

I have also made a couple of changes to your code, but the main issue was the fact the `wrapped` function was never getting invoked.

```py
class MyLogger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__logger = None

    def init_logger(self, name, verbosity):
        # extract log level based on verbosity flag
        logging_levels = [logging.CRITICAL, logging.INFO, logging.DEBUG]
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging_levels[verbosity])
        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    @property
    def logger(self):
        return self.__logger


myLogger = MyLogger()


class TraceFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def __call__(self, function):
        name = function.__name__

        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # improved the formatting of arguments
            nicely_formatted_args = ', '.join(args)
            nicely_formatted_kwargs = ', '.join(kwargs)
            arguments = nicely_formatted_args
            if nicely_formatted_kwargs != '':
                arguments = f'{arguments}, {nicely_formatted_kwargs}'
            self.logger.debug(f'{name}({arguments})')
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            self.logger.debug(f'{result}')
            return result

        return wrapped


# (1) @TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)
def echo(message):
    return message.upper()


@click.command('echo')
@click.option('-e', '--echo', 'message', required=True, type=str)
def echo_command(message):
    myLogger.logger.info('echo_command')
    return echo(message)


@click.group()
@click.option('-v', 'verbosity', count=True) # <- made verbosity a count argument so you can extract all of your levels based on -v -vv -vvv etc.
def main(verbosity):
    myLogger.init_logger(__name__, verbosity)
    # (2) 
    # Invoking the function with argument 'Foo'
    TraceFunction(myLogger.logger)(echo)("Foo")


def run_logging():
    main.add_command(echo_command)
    main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_logging()
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back earlier, had a rough time at work. Okay, so back to your answer. Yes and no. Yes, in terms of you made the error go away like that, but no it doesn't work. Your solution logs Foo as echo argument. I'll update my question with a clean example.